# How to insert Latex macro inside R markdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am new to Latex. I try to use R markdown together with Latex formatting to generate PDF like [this](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/subhash-chandrans-cv/wbkdwkvbzfff). I want to add rating marker as in the example (English, Spanish, German), but I could not figure out how to do this in R markdown. Here are some sample code to generate the rating marker (which I put in the template file `style.tex`:

```latex
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{accent}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{heading}{black}
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
\newcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

\newcommand{\cvskill}[2]{%
\textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\hfill
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}{%
     \space{\ifnumgreater{\x}{#2}{\color{body!30}}{\color{accent}}\ratingmarker}}\par%
}
```

When I use `\cvskill{English}{5}` in R markdown and Knit, I got the following error:

```
    ! Undefined control sequence.
l.119 \cvskill
```

How to achieve something like this?
[image]

**Update**:The following is what I put in the R markdown.

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    template: "style.tex"
geometry: margin=1in
---

\cvskill{English}{5}

\divider

\cvskill{Spanish}{4}

\divider

\cvskill{German}{3}
```

Comment: Can you show us a minimal Rmd file that produces the error?

Comment: In the YAML header user `includes: in_header: style.tex`. See section 3.3.7.3 [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html)

Comment: @RalfStubner please see the updates.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer is it ok to put in the template file which I also used for formatting the body of the text?

Comment: The `style.tex` file you quote cannot be used as a `template` file, since there is no `\documentclass` etc. In principle you can put all these commands into a **valid** template file. Or use `includes` as suggested above, probably together with a suitable `documentclass` parameter.

Comment: @RalfStubner sorry for the confusion. The `style.tex` is a valid template file, and is forked from [here](https://github.com/svmiller/svm-r-markdown-templates/blob/master/svm-latex-cv.tex). What I did is to add the above rating marker command at the end of the template file.

Comment: Then please create a [mcve], i.e. reduce `style.tex` as far as possible while still producing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that I made a mistake by putting the rating marker function codes `\newcommand ...` outside of the `\documentclass` in `style.tex`. Once I corrected this error, it worked well.